# Abstract base class with an abstract method that will take one or two values (Scala)

Tags: scala, abstract-class, abstract

I'm thinking of how to write an abstract base class with an abstract method that will take either one ro two `Int` values. Something like:

```
abstract class Foo {
  def doSomething(???): Unit
}
```

The best I can think of so far is declaring a parameter as a `Vector[Int]` that will either hold one or two values, or perhaps to better enforce the maximum of two values a `Tuple2[Int, Int]`.

I'd like to do this as I want to pass around algorithms within an `Actor` system, and I want certain messages to enforce the type of the algorithm instead of passing around an `Any`, hence the abstract base class.

Is this the best way, or are there better ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically this would just be done with an overloaded method.  Then when calling the method on `Bar`, they can pass in either one or two things:

```
abstract class Foo {
  def doSomething(a: Int): Int
  def doSomething(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  def doSomething(a: Int): Int = a
  def doSomething(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a * b
}
```

Or alternatively, using a default parameter (which still allows you to do `new Bar().doSomething(5)`)

```
abstract class Foo {
  def doSomething(a: Int, b: Int = 1): Int
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  def doSomething(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a * b
}
```

But it sounds like you want to do this in a way where you always call the same `Foo` method, so in that case, you can do the polymorphism on the parameter:

```
trait Thing
case class Thing1(a: Int) extends Thing
case class Thing2(a: Int, b: Int) extends Thing

abstract class Foo {
  def doSomething(t: Thing): Int
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  def doSomething(t: Thing): Int = t match {
    case Thing1(a) => a
    case Thing2(a, b) => a * b
  }
}
```

Or, since you just have two choices, you can do the same thing with an `Either`:

```
abstract class Foo {
  def doSomething(t: Either[Int, (Int, Int)]): Int
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  def doSomething(t: Either[Int, (Int, Int)]): Int = t match {
    case Left(a) => a
    case Right((a, b)) => a * b
  }
}
```